# PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions... and I change nothing

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, permissions

I know this question has been asked a few times, but I couldn't find any working answer.
I'm using Google App Engine and Firestore (Database location: eur3 - europe-west).

A few days ago, my simple app was working like a charm and more precisely Firestore was working.
I could test/use it locally through `nodemon` or online (when deployed).

Since this morning, and I change nothing, it doesn't work anymore locally.
**I can't access my DB locally anymore, but I can when deployed to GAE.**

Locally I got this error and this is a DB access issue:

> PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions. {"code":7,"details":"Missing or insufficient permissions.","metadata":{}}

My code to access DB has always been as simple as:

```js
// service/firestore.js
const Firestore = require("@google-cloud/firestore");
const db = new Firestore();
module.exports.db = db;
```

Do you have any clue why I can't write/read locally to Firestore this morning?
(BTW I've never modified `security rules` and it has always been working).
Thanks

Comment: Maybe this article, [How to fix Firestore Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) might help.

Comment: Did @Alex Mamo solution worked? We might need some more details on [how to reproduce your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you out. Could you show us your `security rules`? Is the user authenticated?